# Probleme overriding Devise Registration Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, devise, haml

I'm actually trying to override my devise registration controller, but I'm faced with a problem. When I tried to call my custom registration controller from a form, my custom registration controller isn't call.

**routes.rb:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }
end
```

**app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb**

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  #POST /users
  def create
    puts "ENTER"
    #super
  end
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception, prepend: true
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:firstname, :lastname, :address, :phone, :gender])
  end
end
```

When I call it from Postman I get those logs:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-22 11:32:16 +0200
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"test@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "firstname"=>"test", "lastname"=>"test1", "phone"=>"123456789", "address"=>"test", "gender"=>"test"}}
ENTER
No template found for Users::RegistrationsController#create, rendering head 
:no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 1065ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

But when I'm calling it from this Haml form:

```
.form-zone-container
    .form-zone
      %form.form{"accept-charset" => "UTF-8", :action => "/users", :enctype => "multipart/form-data", :method => "post"}
        .title
          Personal informations
        .radio-btn
          #form_gender
            %input#form_gender_1.check{"aria-required" => "true", :name => "user[gender]", :required => "required", :type => "radio", :value => "Male"}/
            %label.required{:for => "form_gender_1"} Male
            %input#form_gender_0.check{"aria-required" => "true", :name => "user[gender]", :required => "required", :type => "radio", :value => "Female"}/
            %label.required{:for => "form_gender_0"} Female
        %input{:name => "user[firstname]", :placeholder => "name", :type => "text", :value => (@params[:user]['firstname'] if @params[:user] && @params[:user]['firstname'])}/
        %input{:name => "user[lastname]", :placeholder => "Last name", :type => "text", :value => (@params[:user]['lastname'] if @params[:user] && @params[:user]['lastname'])}/
        %input{:name => "user[email]", :placeholder => "Email", :type => "email", :value => (@params[:user]['email'] if @params[:user] && @params[:user]['email'])}/
        %input{:name => "user[password]", :placeholder => "password", :type => "password"}/
        %input{:class => "confirm_password", :placeholder => "Confirm your password", :type => "password"}/
        %input{:name => "user[phone]", :placeholder => "Phone", :type => "tel"}/
        %input.place{:name => "user[address]", :placeholder => "Address", :type => "text", :value => (@params[:meeting]['address'] if @params[:meeting] && @params[:meeting]['address'])}/
        %a.little-green-btn{:onclick => "$(this).closest('form').submit()"} Send
```

I get those logs:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-22 11:39:37 +0200
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"gender"=>"Male", "firstname"=>"test", "lastname"=>"test", "email"=>"test@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "phone"=>"test", "address"=>"test"}}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 35ms (ActiveRecord: 3.8ms)

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-22 11:39:37 +0200
Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb (2.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 37ms (Views: 5.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

In this last case, I don't know what is going on, there is no "Enter" in my logs. The only thing, I noticed that changed is:

`Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as */*` to `Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as HTML`

Hope someone could help me with this problem.

Thank in advance,

***UPDATE***

**rake routes**

```
                    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                 Controller#Action
          new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                    devise/sessions#new
              user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                    devise/sessions#create
      destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                   devise/sessions#destroy
         new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)               devise/passwords#new
        edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)              devise/passwords#edit
             user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#update
                           PUT    /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#update
                           POST   /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#create
  cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                     users/registrations#cancel
     new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                    users/registrations#new
    edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                       users/registrations#edit
         user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                            users/registrations#update
                           PUT    /users(.:format)                            users/registrations#update
                           DELETE /users(.:format)                            users/registrations#destroy
                           POST   /users(.:format)                            users/registrations#create
```

Try to do it to with form_for:

```
      = form_for @user, url: "/users", html: {class: 'form'} do |f|
        .title
          Personal informations
        .radio-btn
          #form_gender
            = f.radio_button(:gender, "Male", checked: true)
            = f.label(:gender, "Male")
            = f.radio_button(:gender, "Female")
            = f.label(:gender, "Female")
        = f.text_field(:firstname)
        = f.text_field(:lastname)
        = f.email_field(:email)
        = f.password_field(:password)
        = f.telephone_field(:phone)
        = f.text_field(:address)
        = f.submit("Send")
```

Still getting the same results.

Comment: You're in the right way, try adding a require_no_authentication before callback in your registrations controller `before_action :require_no_authentication, only: :create`.

Comment: Try to add it but without success, still facing the same issue :(

Comment: Can you add the output of rails routes?

Comment: Do you mean `rake routes` ?

Comment: just f.y.i. the rails routes command is used in Rails version 5+, they both do the same

Comment: Try with a form_for instead a "common" form tag, and passing the url instead an action attribute, like: `<%= form_for(url: '/users')  do |f| %>`, maybe you'll also need to pass the resource.

Comment: I tried to do it to with form_for but without success. I updated my quesion with the form_for I used.

Comment: Try with `<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
`

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I had to solved it fast and I made it with Jquery